# Как починить поехавшие блоки картинок CSS

Tags: html, css

Необходимо убрать расстояние между разными строками(блоками).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непосредственно css

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
  content:" ";
  display:table;
}

.clearfix:after{
  clear:both;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1050px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.gallery{
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-item{
  float:left;
  background: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, #B9ECFE, #B9ECFE 10px, #82DDFF 10px, #82DDFF 20px);
  width: 18%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), -5px -10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.gallery-item img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Как вариант вы можете использовать [многоколоночный текст](https://habr.com/company/microsoft/blog/143158/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не сложно такое делать

Обычные свойства css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.items {
  column-count: 3;
  column-rule: 20px;
  max-width: 888px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x259" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam, deserunt?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Assumenda beatae nesciunt dignissimos omnis ad eius provident sint quas vitae doloribus?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x400" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sed perspiciatis eum rerum illo.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x320" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique voluptas reiciendis vero corporis asperiores necessitatibus! Libero, architecto odio qui quos, hic beatae a veritatis nam, tempora suscipit repudiandae non corporis.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nostrum officiis quia similique ratione provident deleniti fugit cum repudiandae praesentium, fuga dolore.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x120" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, eos.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x300" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti veniam excepturi quasi, vitae asperiores fugit itaque nulla aut laboriosam. Harum quia ea perferendis repudiandae deserunt deleniti optio sed quasi aliquid.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```